# Instantiated Object returns Null outside Start method

Tags: unity, c#, instancing

I'm attempting to access an instantiated 'goalTemp' GameObject from a different function inside the same script. I'm getting the information in the Start method, assigning the GameObject find/get component script code to a variable. When I'm printing the results outside the Start method, it returns null, even though the 'goal' variable is public.

```
void Start() 
 {
     GameObject goalTemp = (GameObject)Instantiate(goal,respawnGoalLocation[CreateLevel.currentLevel-1],Quaternion.identity);
     goal = goalTemp.gameObject;
 }
```

---

```
public void Explode()
 {
     Debug.Log(goal);
     Instantiate(rockParticle, goal.transform.position, goal.transform.rotation);
     Instantiate(explosionParticle, goal.transform.position, goal.transform.rotation);
 }
```

---

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your time!

Comment: `goal = goalTemp.gameObject;` seems weird to me (I'm no expert in Unity). What if you used `goal = goalTemp;` instead? (`goalTemp.gameObject` seems to be the constructor of the object.)

Comment: goalTemp is already a GameObject you don't need to refer to .gameObject though I don't think that would cause your issue either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see why your code would not work outside of setting the goalTemp(GameObjects) variable to the .gameObject property since its already a GameObject, I am unsure if this would cause any issues though as that should just reference the same thing.

I set up a quick plain simple demo to show you how I would do it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    //the prefab we will spawn
    public GameObject prefab;
    //a reference to this instance, normally if there's more than one you put them in a list or array or whatever
    private GameObject prefabInstance;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        //assign the prefabinstance here
        prefabInstance = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        //debug it on space pressed
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log(prefabInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I managed to solved it but your answer is exactly the better way to do it. Thanks!